# MySQL PHP Query Invalid - Can't find column

Tags: php, mysql, sql, variables

**UPDATE:
The suggestion of the '' worked around $username. Thanks! But now, the table isn't actually getting updated from the $lastLoginTime.**

I have some problem with my query that I can't seem to figure out for the life of me and I am at a halt.

Let's take a look at the code.

```
function checkTOS($preusergrab){
include("includes/opendb.php");

$query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='".$preusergrab."'";
$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
    $resultset[] = $row;
    $TOS = $row['acceptTOS'];
    }

mysql_free_result($result);

 if($TOS == 1){
 // return to processor

    $lastLoginTime = time();

    $query = mysql_query("UPDATE users 
                    SET lastLoginTime = '$lastLoginTime' 
                        WHERE username = $username");

                        if (!$query) {

             die('<br>Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
            }


 }elseif($TOS == 0 || $TOS = ''){
    header("Location: http://partner.domain.com/terms.php?action=show");
    die();
}else{
echo 'Internal Application Error:';
echo 'Value unrecognizable.';
echo '<br>Please alert someone at user@domain.com';
die();
}
 }
```

Now, where the problem comes in is at this section:

```
    $lastLoginTime = time();

    $query = mysql_query("UPDATE users 
                    SET lastLoginTime = '$lastLoginTime' 
                        WHERE username = $username");

                        if (!$query) {

             die('<br>Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
            }
```

It says the following:

```
   Invalid query: Unknown column 'theuser' in 'where clause'
```

In this case, 'theuser' is the user that $preusergrab is representing.

In my table, the username is the primary key, row 0.

What could possibly be invalid if I know the row is there and everything else works?

Comment: i recommend putting your SQL query into a variable, echoing it, then copy and pasting it into PHPMyAdmin. This will tell you whether its your PHP or SQL that is at fault.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try to

```
$query = mysql_query("UPDATE users 
                SET lastLoginTime = '$lastLoginTime' 
                    WHERE username = '$username'");
```

Comment: check that `time()` returns date in appropriate format understandably to mysql

Comment: Yes, standard unix timestamp, i use it everywhere else on the app. Just echoed the variable as well and it showed the timestamp.

Comment: print out `"UPDATE users 
                SET lastLoginTime = '$lastLoginTime' 
                    WHERE username = '$username'"` for debugging (post it here please) and run this query by console mysql-client. let's see )

Answer (score 1):

It should be:

```
WHERE username = '$username'");
```

Note the apostrophes I added around your $username' variable.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you forgot to quote the $username, quote like so '$username'

```
$query = mysql_query("UPDATE users 
SET lastLoginTime = '$lastLoginTime' 
WHERE username = '$username'");

if (!$query) {
die('<br>Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
}
```

Comment: Well that worked, but some reason it doesnt update the table.. I updated my question.